# SQL Database Design - Single column table - SELECT efficiency?

Tags: sql, database, foreign-keys, primary-key

I'm putting together a database which I want to be very efficient for `SELECT` queries as all the data in the database will be created once and multiple read-only queries run on that data.

I have multiple tables (~20) and each have a composite primary key which is made up of a combination of `Time` (`int`) and ***either*** `ProductID` (`int`) or `ServiceID` (`int`) depending on the table.

I understand to maximize read/`SELECT` efficiency I should generally de-normalize the data to prevent expensive table joins.

So considering that, if I want to optimize read performance should I

1. have 3 single-column tables containing all the possible `Time`, `ProductID` and `ServiceID` values. Then have these as a foreign key in each of the tables.
2. keep all the 20 tables completely independent to optimize `SELECT` performance.

Comment: Databases should be optimized based on the data being represented and the expected query load.  Your question doesn't provide enough information.  In some cases, having 20 tables with joins might be the most efficient.  In some cases, denormalizing everything into one table might be the most efficient.

Comment: Basic rule: *Normalize until it hurts, then de-normalize until it works* - so **FIRST** make sure you put everything into a normalized form (at least 3NF). Then see if your queries work fast enough, optimize your queries, add indexes as needed - and only as a **last resort** start de-normalizing again if you can't get the necessary performance.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I should have mentioned that the queries will be extracting data from only one of the 20 tables for any given query. The 20 tables have 3-8 columns in each.

Comment: Sometimes partitioning on date/time (rather than having time in a key) can produce huge increases in read speed, but as has already been said, you haven't really given enough information about the structure of your data and the type of queries you will be running.

Comment: For this application Time will be a local time counter (int) rather than a date/time stamp.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest SELECT statement is an index SEEK from a single table.

If you only care about SELECT performance, and don't have to worry about writing new data to the tables, then design your tables around your expected queries, so that all the data you need for each query can be found in one table, and that table has an index on the expected search arguments.

Comment: "The fastest SELECT statement is an index SEEK from a single table" Depends how much data you need to access. Sometimes table scans are faster. Often quoted rule-of-thumb states that an index only makes sense if you query less than 10% of the records. On the other end of the spectrum, you can build an index that can satisfy queries without ever touching the table at all.